# Web Scraping in R / Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, rvest

I need to extract data from `https://eservices.dha.gov.ae/DHASearch/UIPages/ProfessionalSearch.aspx?PageLang=En`. I need 4 columns -"name","gender", "Titles" ,"Hospital Name", "Contact details". The "Titles" info will be shown when you click on a name.  Another problem I am facing is to extract info from multiple pages. In total, there are 10071 records. I need info of all these records. Currently I am using rvest package in R but it's throwing error. See the code below -

```
   library(rvest)
    session = html_session("https://eservices.dha.gov.ae/DHASearch/UIPages/ProfessionalSearch.aspx")
    form = html_form(session)[[1]]
```

**Error : Subscript out of bounds**

I am open to solution in Python. I am novice in using beautifulsoup in Python. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: You should learn Python Scrapy. When you say `I am open to solution in Python`, then I would suggest you use that because you will get a lot more help here. Code it in scrapy and then ask specific issues if you have any

Comment: I don't know R or rvest, but BeautifulSoup makes this very easy. It uses the requests library. So you can do `website = requests.get("url")` this will get you a website object you can manipulate. Then if you wanted to get each row in the table (is it a table, I'm just guessing) you could get all of the table elements using something like `soup = BeautifulSoup(website), rows = soup.findAll('tr')`. There many other things you can add to narrow down your search. Look at the documentation here: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/. If you this would be easier just leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

If you have the right to scrape all this personal information then the best way to go about it would be to use selenium in python and a web driver to navigate the pages by calling the js function call used for each paginated page and pull the page source for each of them. This is probably your best bet seen as the data is loaded using Javascript calls.